# How to update $scope value without $watch for cross-updates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need cross-update values for both objects

```
$scope.price = 0
$scope.amount = 1
$scope.total = 0

$scope.$watch('price', function(){
  $scope.total = parseFloat( $scope.price * $scope.amount ).toFixed(2);
})

$scope.$watch('total', function(){
  $scope.price = parseFloat( $scope.total / $scope.amount ).toFixed(2);
})
```

And i need to disable $watch when i update value from $watch function (maybe something like `setViewValue` )

What can i do?

Question is: How to update $scope value without digest (skip $watch function)?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the $watch section here:

[Angular Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope/)

> **Returns**
>
> function()     Returns a deregistration function for this listener.

so:

> ```
> var disabler = $scope.$watch('price', function(){
>   $scope.total = parseFloat( $scope.price * $scope.amount ).toFixed(2);
> })
>
> //this will de-register the watch
> disabler();
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it not what i need. I just want set new value in $scope.total or $scope.price inside $watch function without call any $watch listeners but update the view. I have no idea how explain this simpler.

Comment: You can't disable the watch (using my code), update the values, then re-enable the watch?

Comment: Yeah, but it so strange construction. Why Angular team not make simple method like $scope.$setViewValue('price', 222) or $scope.$skipDigest()
So sad...